# Getting Failed to resolve error for retrofit 2.+ but working fine for version 1.9.0

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

[image]I am getting Failed to resolve Retrofit:2.+ but when i replace with 1.9.0, there is no error.Help me what need to be done.Also i am using Android studio 2.3.3

```
dependencies
{
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: use compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0' ie compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed retrofit version 2 in link for retrofit2

use

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'`

instead of

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.2'`

Comment: @shankervennam really? can you try this? `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0' `

Comment: i tried that first..i tried all versions with 2.+...but no luck

Comment: @shankervennam I got the same error, it's `com.squareup.retrofit` but when  I changed `com.squareup.retrofit2`, it works find.

Comment: @shankervennam no problem & if you're done, please mark it! thank you.